# SSH refusing connection after chown command

Tags: ssh, virtual-machines, centos7, chown

I have SSH access to a Centos 7 virtual machine. I wanted to change the permissions on the apache folder (var/www) on my user in order to edit the files remotely, but I erroneously performed `chown -R <user> /var/`. Now I cannot SSH anymore. How can I solve this problem? What could be the reason?
EDIT: I don't have access to the physical machine that hosts the virtual machine

Answer (score 2):

```
rpm --setugids openssh-server
```

You may also need to restart the service

Comment: should I perform this on the remote machine?

Comment: On the machine you performed the accidental `chown -R`, yes. Since you cannot SSH into the system, this will probably require accessing the console of the VM. If you don't have console access to your VM, you may need to contact the administrator of the physical host.

Comment: What is the difference between this command and giving back the permissions with `chown -R root /var/`?

Comment: @Francesco: if root is the rightful owner of the files, then what is preventing root from reading and writing them?